# Unity выдаёт ошибку

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using TMPro;

public class LevelControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshPro text;
    private Timer NewTimer;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    { 
        NewTimer = new Timer(10);
        NewTimer.Go();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        text.text = NewTimer.Time().ToString();
    }
}


public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int timer;

    public Timer(int n)
    {
        timer = n;
    }

    public void Go()
    {
        StartCoroutine(TimerStart());
    }
    private IEnumerator TimerStart()
    {
        if (timer > 0)
        {
            timer -= 1;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            StartCoroutine(TimerStart());
        }
    }
    public bool CheckStop()
    {
        if (timer == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public int Time()
    {
        return timer;
    }
}
```

Я создал вот такой код для таймера в своей игре. В visual studio нет ошибок, однако при запуске появляются предупреждение и ошибка:

```
You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword.  This is not allowed.  MonoBehaviours can only be added using AddComponent(). Alternatively, your script can inherit from ScriptableObject or no base class at all
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:.ctor ()
Timer:.ctor (int) (at Assets/Scripts/LevelControl.cs:226)
LevelControl:Start () (at Assets/Scripts/LevelControl.cs:40)

NullReferenceException
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine (System.Collections.IEnumerator routine) (at <42a5878ce129403083acccf18e43363f>:0)
Timer.Go () (at Assets/Scripts/LevelControl.cs:233)
LevelControl.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/LevelControl.cs:41)
```

В переменную text я через инспектор прикрепил TextMeshPro

Comment: А вы можете прочитать ошибку? Вот что там написано? Не уж то этого намека вам мало?

Comment: Я не знаю что значит эта ошибка

Comment: "Вы пытаетесь создать `MonoBehaviour` через `new`. Это невозможно. `MonoBehaviour` может быть добавлен через `AddComponent()`." Вроде вполне себе жирный намек на то, что вы не можете в коде делать `new Timer(10)`...

Comment: я понял что нужно изменить на NewTimer = gameObject.AddComponent<Timer>();, но тогда я не могу использовать конструктор.

Comment: Уважаемый, вы же программист, вы должны, нет, даже обязаны, пытаться в первую очередь разобраться с задачей самостоятельно. Не смотрите так просто на ошибку, она вам говорит что `new` нельзя, это уже звоночек, что вы делаете что-то не то, а значит надо идти в документацию и искать как правильно. Я не Unity разработчик и сказать вам как "правильно" не могу. На сколько я знаю, скрипты кидают в юнити на объекты. А про конструктор, ну ведь можно написать `unity3d addcomponent constructor` и найти допустим [это](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1245158), где используется `.initialize(...);`.

Comment: Для участников репутацией: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/unity3d/synonyms голосуем за мерж меток для юнити.